# QT5 SQLite "Parameter count mismatch" problem

Tags: sqlite, qt, qt5

I am using QT5 with SQLite, I want to put some data into database. Here is my code:

```cpp
database = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE");
database.setDatabaseName("QTappDB.db");
if(database.open()){
    QSqlQuery query;
    query.prepare("INSERT INTO note(noteText) VALUES (?);");
    query.bindValue(0, "name");
    query.exec();
}
```

and all I got from this code is:

```
"Parameter count mismatch"
```

I have tried my query in database, it is working.

I have already tried other type of bindings in the documentation. All four types, with or without **placeholder**, including **addBindValue** but none of them worked. Every time I got the same error.

And I want to say I have read every single problem and solution for this but none of them worked. I don't know what is the problem.

I am using QT5 (5.15.1), SQLite, Macos Catalina

Comment: share QTappDB.db

Comment: what do you mean with share ? release here ?

Comment: The QTappDB.db is a file, if you could upload it to drive, dropbox, etc and share the link to download it then that would be great. It would also be good if you indicate what type of fields table "note" has

Comment: let me make it clear, it is a simple database which is empty, it has no data. note is a table, noteText is the only column of it. there is nothing more.

Comment: Could you show the code or procedure with which you create the table "note"? Or do you think the table will be created magically? Please provide a [mre]

Comment: I have created it inside database. I am using a program called "DB browser for SQLite", I created the database and table first. I can run queries inside this program and it is working. I can see the database, I can see the table. I can add data, I can delete. The code before these are not related to database.

Comment: What I suspect is that you are not using a database created with that tool, I recommend you not to use relative but absolute paths so change `database.setDatabaseName("QTappDB.db");` to `database.setDatabaseName("/fullpath/of/QTappDB.db");`, OR put the "QTappDB.db" in the build folder generated when compiling

Comment: well, you might be right but there is another problem right now. I have made the change ```database.setDatabaseName("~/Desktop/QTprojects/Notepad/QTappDB.db");``` but now, it cant open the database now. Before that, it can open it. Also this ```QTappDB.db``` file was already in the same file with ```.pro``` file. did you mean this folder with build folder ?

Comment: No, the folder where the .pro is is not the compilation folder but the build folder where the executable is. On the other hand do not use "~" but "/home/USER"

Comment: ok, it is done now. Thanks for the solution. I have change the path name correctly then it is done. the only thing that I didnt understand is the build folder. There are 2 different folder near to main folder. Debug folder and release folder. they both have the executable file. Other then these two, there is no folder. Or did you mean QT executable application folder with build folder ? Like main QT folder ?

Comment: I mean the "Debug" and "Release" folders depending on how you launch the application.

Comment: allright, thanks for the help, best wishes.